# Why is some jQuery/javascript code being skipped?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am currently coding an instant chatbox using jquery which will show the latest chat on top (refreshes when user send data via post request)
and push the oldest chat downward and remove it.

The problem is that if more than one latest chat is retrieved(for example, 2), two new div will be prepended but only one oldest div is removed instead of two...I tried timeout but it didnt work either..

Below are the code snippets I believe which got problem in it.

```
function showData(currentchatstyle, data, final){
   var newchatstyle;
    if (currentchatstyle == "chatone") {
        newchatstyle = "chattwo";
    }
    else {
        newchatstyle = "chatone";
    }

    $('div[class^="chat"]:first').before('<div class="' + newchatstyle + '" style="display:none;">' + data + ' </div>');
    $('div[class^="chat"]:first').slideDown(500,"swing", function(){
        $('div[class^="chat"]').last().fadeOut(500, function() {
            $(this).remove(); 
        });
    });

    return newchatstyle;
}

$('input[name="content"]').keyup(function(key) {
    if (key.which==13) {

        var author = $('input[name="author"]').val();
        var content = $('input[name="content"]').val();
        var lastnum = $('postn:first').text();
        var chatstyle = $('div[class^="chat"]:first').attr("class");

        $.post(
            "chatajax.php",
            { "author": author, "content": content, "lastnum": lastnum }, 
            function(data) {
                var msg = data.split("|~|");
                for (var i = 0; i < msg.length; i++) {
                    chatstyle = showData(chatstyle, msg[i], true);
                }
            }
        ); 
    }
});
```

Help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: $('div[class^="chat"]:last').remove(); kind of suggests that only a single div will be removed. Sounds like you're hitting a "threading" issue. You probably need a separate routine that looks at the "size" of the returned number of divs and removes enough of them to maintain a maximum "list" size.

Comment: A first glance: you declared `newchatstyle` at the wrong place. It should be outside the for-blocks, but you declared it inside. Also you should format your code better.

Comment: You shouldn't call `$` with the new selector in the callback of `.fadeOut`, instead you shall use `$(this)`.

Comment: @JeffWatkins : the showData function only create one new div and delete one old div at a time,i called it multiple time so it should works...hm...Thanks for your suggestion..I will try it..

Comment: @soulchild, but if the DOM update itself doesn't happen synchronously, you will see the defect you mentioned.

Comment: @soulchild I believe when you change it to use `$(this)` in the callback function, your situation will change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you do select also currently-fading-out divs with `$('div[class^="chat"]').last()`, as you don't `remove` them immediately but in the animation callback. You for example might immediately remove the `chat` class so it won't be selected in the next call to `showData`.

Also, you should only use one class "chat" for a similar divs and for a zebra-style give them independent classes.

```
var chatstyle = "one";
function showData(data, final){
    chatstyle = chatstyle=="one" ? "two" : "one";
    var newDiv = $('<div class="chat '+chatstyle+'" style="display:none;">'+data+'</div>');
    $('div.chat:first').before(newDiv);
    newDiv.slideDown(500, "swing", function(){
        $('div.chat:last').removeClass('chat').fadeOut(500, function() {
//                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
            $(this).remove(); 
        });
    });
}
function post(data) {
    return $.post(
        "chatajax.php",
        data,
        function(data) {
            var msg = data.split("|~|");
            for (var i = 0; i < msg.length; i++)
                showData(msg[i], true); // what's "final"?
        }
    );
}

$('input[name="content"]').keyup(function(key) {
    if (key.which==13)
       post({
           "author": $('input[name="author"]').val(),
           "content": $('input[name="content"]').val(),
           "lastnum": $('postn:first').text() // I'm sure this should not be extracted from the DOM
       });
});
```

Comment: I removed the fadeout and went straight to remove() and it worked! Thanks! But is it possible to have fadeout animation before removing?